# How to fix map is not a function error in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-functional-component

I'm having an error `"map" is not a function` when making an API call. I just started learning react and APIs not too long ago. I tried changing the state to object and got undefined, as `[]`.
I got map is not a function. maybe i'm missing something calling the API. Here's the code below

```
function Facility() {
  
  const [facility, setFacility] = useState([]);

 try {
      const fetch = await Axios.get(
        //API
      )
      //setFacility(fetch.data);
    console.log('result', fetch.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


  return (      
        <Table  >
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell />
              <TableCell >
                Facility Code
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell >
                Facility Name
              
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {facility.map((item, idx) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <TableRow
                    key={idx}
                  >
                   
                    <TableCell >
                      {item.facility_code}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{item.facility_name}</TableCell>
                   
                  </TableRow>
                 
                </>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
    
   
  );
}

export default Facility;
```

Data returned from API below

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "facility_code": 148312,
            "facility_name": "Phc Marit",
        },
        {
            "facility_code": 767529,
            "facility_name": "FPL",       
        },   
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to map over data from API using material-ui table but I get facility.map is not a function. Please help me with a solution to this implementation.

Comment: you probably not using `res.data`.

Comment: A wild guess is that you are setting the state of `facility` after the API call, but is then no longer an array (prob an object?)

Comment: try  fetch.data.data in the setFacility, because the API response is may be sending data inside "data" so you need to use data.data to get the array. also 
check facility && facility.length && facility.map(....

Answer (score 8):

I created this example on codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-joana-xfybt?file=/src/App.js

There are multiple things that can go wrong.

First of all, you have to validate to have data before using the map. So you can do something like:

**Step 1:**

So, first change:

```js
{facility.map((item, idx) => {
```

to this:

```
{facility && facility.map && facility.map((item, idx) => {
```

**Step 2:**

Also, take into consideration how you're receiving the answer, usually with axios. Because `axios` returns `response`. If you. want to access the body of the response is `response.data`, if your body also has data. Probably you need to do something like: `fetch.data.data`

(Check the getData function)

Comment: I tried your sandbox without `facility && facility.map && ` and it still worked, this is not the main fix here, `step 2` is.

Comment: Yep, you're right, it's the main problem but there is unknown code. So, because of that, I prefer to include the validation of the object and if it has map :)

Answer (score 1):

When using Axios you have to use

```
fetch.data.data
```

I Also suggest you to use React useEffect with you do API Calls. The Recommended way of doing this is below.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  let [facility, setFacility] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
    axios({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "YOUR_API_ENDPOINT_HERE",
      "headers": {}, "params": {}
    })
      .then((response) => {

        const APIResponse = response.data // This is response data from AXIOS

        console.log("response: ", APIResponse.data) // This is response data from API

        setFacility(APIResponse.data) // Only Response from API is set in state

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [fetchData])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table  >
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell >
              Facility Code
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell >
              Facility Name
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {
            facility.map((item, idx) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <TableRow
                    key={idx}
                  >
                    <TableCell >
                      {item.facility_code}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {item.facility_name}
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </>
              );
            })
          }
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not using useEffect and was getting infinite loops. Adapted your solution and the data rendering also worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to map a list that isn't there yet? Try doing this

```
{facility && facility.map((item, idx) => {
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: checking facility will not solve his problem. rather he will not get the result, the issue is where he setting the value to the facility. 
checking facility and facility.length is a safe way to avoid error. but he will not get the result by this

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @sojin

Answer (score 0):

```
{facility.map((item, idx) => {
                  <TableRow
                    key={idx}
                  >
                   
                    <TableCell >
                      {item.facility_code}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{item.facility_name}</TableCell>
                   
                  </TableRow>
})}
```